# How to get FPS of using a loop to download still images?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an local network IP camera that dumps its frames into a still JPG image (I don't know the frequency it does this). I have a test HTML document that has some JavaScript that makes an `<img>` element update every X ms to this still image. This creates a "fake" video.

I know how often I'm making the element update (my desired FPS) however it'll never be the same because it has to fetch the image from the source which takes extra ms.

**Is there an easy & efficient way to accurately time this, to determine the *real* FPS?**

My code:

`<img id="video" src="" width="704" height="576" alt="Camera not running" />`

```
loop = function() { 
    setTimeout(function() {
        //Force update...
        document.getElementById('video').src = '/location/of/raw/image.jpg';

        loop();
    }, (1000 / parseInt(fps)));
}

loop();
```

Note: I use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` so I can modify the desired FPS at any time.

Note: This is only part of the full script. I don't get the video element every loop.

I don't want to use server-side programming. I want to keep this to HTML and JS.

Comment: If you have a server side script like php, you can check the file updated time and tell javascript to fetch the image when an updated image is available

Comment: There is no PHP involved. I want to keep it to HTML and JS. The file I'm getting is from a device I have no control over.

Comment: Short answer - No, you cannot get the image to update accurately and precisely because network latency is variable and you cannot control or calculate it.